# Changing Color of JButton with mouseListener

Tags: java, swing, button, mouseevent, mouse-listeners

Im trying to make a simple tictactoe game. To create the grid I used and array of JButtons.

```
mouseClicker m1 = new mouseClicker();//check for click

for (int i=0; i<9;i++) {//create buttons
            buttons[i] = new JButton();
            buttons[i].addMouseListener(m1);
            gameSpots.add(buttons[i]);
            
        }
```

In order to track a user's click I have a mouseListener for the buttons.

```
public class mouseClicker extends MouseAdapter{ 
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
              System.out.println(e.getSource());
              System.out.println(e.getX()+", "+e.getY());
              System.out.println();  
           }
    }
```

With it currently I can print the source of each JButton clicked but I have no idea how to modify the corresponding button with this info (add an x to the button clicked for example). How could I use the JButton source to achieve this?

Comment: Don't add a MouseListener to a JButton. Use an ActionListener. Else you're in for problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`setText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setText-java.lang.String-) or [`setIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon-javax.swing.Icon-):

```
public class MouseClicker extends MouseAdapter {    
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getSource());
        System.out.println(e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());
        System.out.println();
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("X");
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but how would that look like though? e.getSource().setIcon()?

Comment: Yes, but you have to cast it to `JButton` (or `AbstractButton`) first.